# The Prapancha (Universe) is very very huge

Tags: universe

The Prapancha (Universe) is very very huge and ever expanding and many solar systems are there and Earth is like a dust particle compared to the Prapancha.As of now we know humans exist only in Earth. Why the God(Paramathma) has created Prapancha where he has created humans in a tiny part like Earth...Even considering the three or Fourteen logas the Prapancha is very very huge ...My observation /query is the major  part of Prapancha (Universe) is empty

Comment: Who knows maybe there are more planets where human being are present. This is a great question.

Comment: Each loka has its inhabitants.

Comment: Lord has created tons of universe, not only this. When Lord Krishna showed universal form (virat swaroop) to Arjuna then He told to him that I am Supreme God, Whatever happens is the play of my wish. As per my wish crores of universes being made and as per my wish they gets destroy. Whenever I wish I makes one and when ever I wish, I destroys it.

Comment: “I am Supreme God, Whatever happens is the play of my wish. As per my wish crores of universes being made and as per my wish they gets destroy. Whenever I wish I makes one and when ever I wish, I destroys it.” Yeah, so many statements like these in Hindu texts, seems kinda  clear there are tons of universes, not just this one.